# Wilcoxon matched pair signed rank test after using CEM

Tags: stata, wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-data

Can I run a Wilcoxon matched pair signed rank test after using Coarsened Exact Matching to match data? If yes, please guide me through the process. I use STATA.

Comment: What is CEM? CV doesn't usually do tutorials & we aren't a software support site; be aware that although I think this question is sufficiently on-topic, you may not get guidance on doing this in Stata w/ your answer.

Comment: Is CEM *coarsened exact matching*?

Comment: @gung if the problem being solved is statistical (rather than simply 'how do I fix my code' or some slightly more sophisticated version of 'which button do I press'-type questions), I think some degree of software specifics when discussing the approach can be on topic (our most popular tag is `r`, after all). But perhaps I mistook your intent.

Comment: Specifically "How to do X in Y" seems to be at least [potentially on topic](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-much-programming-here/).

Comment: Thanks Glen. I have found out hoe it should be done, though it didn't turn out to be useful to me. In case anyone needs to know how things should be done using Coarsened Exact Matching, contact me. Thanks..!

Comment: how the CEM could be done in STATA...... Best
Khan

Comment: @khan Not very sure. I did in R.

Comment: Could you tell us how you did in R? thanks!